# Slicing a list in Python: is there something like -0?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, list-comprehension

I've got a 3D array and would like to split it into many subvolumes.
This is my code so far:

```
# this results in a 3D array
arr = trainMasks[0, 0, :, :, :]
crop = 3
arrs = [arr[x:-(crop - x), y:-(crop - y), z:-(crop - z)]
        for x in range(crop + 1)
        for y in range(crop + 1)
        for z in range(crop + 1)]
```

- If I use `x in range(crop)`, `x` only goes up to `crop - 1`, the last entry in the x dimension is always dropped
- If I use `x in range(crop+1)`, `x` it goes up to `crop`, that will result in a slice `arr[crop:-0, ...]` which has the shape `[0, y_dim, z_dim]`

I know the usual answer, just drop the upper limit, like this: `arr[crop:, :, :]`. Usually that's quite convenient. But how do I do that in the list comprehension ?

Comment: Yes there is such thing as negative and positive zero >>> np.NZERO  -0.0
  >>> np.PZERO   0.0     >>> np.NZERO < np.PZERO False     >>> np.NZERO == np.PZERO  True    Not quite what you are expecting but useful for representing numbers.  there is also the NaN an Infinity variants as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cases like this it is better to avoid negative indexes.

Remeber that for `i>0`, `a[-i]` is equivalent to `a[len(a)-i]`.  But in your case, you also need to work for `i==0`.

This works:

```
d1, d2, d3 = arr.shape
arrs = [arr[ x : d1-(crop-x), y : d2-(crop-y), z : d3-(crop-z)]
        for x in range(crop + 1)
        for y in range(crop + 1)
        for z in range(crop + 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a ternary `if..else` with `None`:

```
>>> 'abc'[:None if 1 else -1]
'abc'
>>> 'abc'[:None if 0 else -1]
'ab'
```

Comment: very interesting. I didn't know that None was possible as an index. I'll accept the other answer since it is a little cleaner, but many thanks for this insight

Comment: That's so simple! I didn't know you could use `None` as in `list[None:None]`. I thought it was limited to integers.